# Parse - инициализация поля пустым массивом строк

Tags: javascript, parse.com

Документация Parse.com говорит о том, что метод add - добавляет в массив значение (по ключу). Как добавить пустой массив - так и не нашел. Сделал так: добавляю значение (у объекта появлется поле с именем fieldArray и содержит в себе один элемент), тут же пытаюсь очистить его - не получается. Что можно сделать ? Или подскажите, как правильно проинициализировать переменную пустым массивом.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myFunction", function(request, response)
{
    var _id = request.params.id;

    var ObjEx = new Parse.Object.extend("ObjEx");
    var query = new Parse.Query(ObjEx);

    query.equalTo("objectId", _id);
    query.limit(1);

    query.find({
            success: function(results)
            {
                results[0].add('fieldArray', "");

                var rarr = results[0].get('fieldArray');
                for( var i = 0; i < rarr.length; ++i)
                {
                    results[0].remove('fieldArray', rarr[i]);
                }
            },
            error: function(results)
            {
                response.error("Spel with Id = " + _spelId + " not found.");
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: обратите внимание, что [parse.com окончательно прекратит свое существование уже через полгода](http://parse.com/migration). рекомендую вам всерьез задуматься о его замене.

Comment: Пусть на здоровье себе закрывается, мне это никак не помешает. Спасибо, конечно, что побеспокоились.